# Handlebars - data not being displayed at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

**Hello everyone,**

I've been playing around with the handlebars trying to make it work in my project, but I keep getting no results when I'm testing the page.

I'm using the JSON data that I have received from another page. Those data should be displayed after compiling the template. But nothing really happens, I just get no results at all.

**get_items_data.js**

```
var source = $("#mytemplate").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

    var Items = Array();
    getting_items_data = true;
    $.get('GetItemsData',function(responseJson) {
        if(responseJson!=null){
            $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                Items.push({ "id": value['item_id'], "blabla": "bla" });
            });
        }
    });
    $('body').append(template(Items));
```

**test.jsp**

```
<script id="mytemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
<table>
    <thead> 
        <th>Items</th> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        {{#each this}} 
        <tr> 
            <td>{{id}}</td> 
            <td>{{blabla}}</td> 
        </tr> 
        {{/each}} 
    </tbody> 
</table> 
</script>
```

**JSON data format:**

```
[{"ItemID":74,"SectionID":4},{"ItemID":78,"SectionID":4}]
```

Any ideas what may be wrong here?

Comment: Try this structure http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/XL5sL/ by moving your LoadItems logic out of the handlebars script template.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work while evaluating the array in $.get().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks your template function is called before you have the data returned, so the `Items` array is empty when the elements are appended to the DOM. Unlike AngularJS, Handlebars is static templating so it won't update the DOM if you update the array later.

Try move that render logic into the callback of `get`:

```
$.get('GetItemsData',function(responseJson) {
    if(responseJson!=null){
        $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
            Items.push({ "id": value['item_id'], "blabla": "bla" });
        });
        $('body').append(template(Items));
    }
});
```

Comment: I've just tested it ...and it looks like this gentelmen is right. It's now working like a charm. Thank you all for helping me out with this issue.

Comment: @Wracker That is essentially the same thing as I did in my second fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whDqv/1/ I simulated your `get` using `setTimeout` to make it asynchronous. You really need to understand why it was breaking in order to not make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function() {
    LoadItems();
});`

Will never execute inside a script of type text/x-handlebars-template.

Also there could be a problem with your variables attempting to get values from the dom before it's loaded.

Here is a dumbed down version that works: http://jsfiddle.net/whDqv/

```
function LoadItems()
{
    var source = $("#mytemplate").html(); 
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var Items = Array();
    getting_items_data = true;
    Items.push({ "id": 1, "blabla": "bla" });
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
    $('body').append(template(Items));

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    LoadItems();
});
```

Comment: Tried removing that, but it didn't help too.

Comment: @Wracker Removing it won't work either you need to put it in separate script tag below the template. I'll try to recreate this in jsfiddle.

Comment: I know what you mean but still it does not work. I've updated my first post, so that you can see how it looks like now.

Comment: @Wracker I've edited my answer. My simple example works fine.

Comment: your example works indeed, however it's not working when I try to add more elements to array while looping through the JSON data. .

Comment: @Wracker Here is an example that loops and works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/whDqv/1/